# Missing Game Center Localisation choice for Irish language

Tags: ios, localization, game-center

I wish to use Game center with my ios app but the app is written in Irish.  On Apple's documentation it states that you can choose a language for Game center but unfortunately the list of languages is very limited and does not include Irish. [image]

How can I go about localising Game Center so that interfaces like this one that Game Center provides can be shown in Irish. [image]:

I don't want to rely on testing if the user's device is running in Irish, but rather I need to be absolutely certain that all elements of the interface are presented in Irish regardless of device or location.

Comment: "the app is written in Irish" - there is no selection for Irish (did you mean Gaelic?) for the same reason that there is no *Americanese* language choice.

Comment: Some people refer to Irish as Gaelic but the correct name is the Irish Language. Americanese is not a language but could be considered a slang or dialect at best.  Irish is a language.

Comment: Pretty sure "Indonesion" has a lot of local dialects as well but they end up falling under the same general category. I suppose for Irish you'd pick the closest relative that Irish folk would know, so English should be okay. Then just add a disclaimer in your app description that the app is actually in Irish and the user ought to be able to understand it. A compromise like that ought to work unless Apple somehow objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't answer the question I asked. I'm sure you didn't mean to suggest that Irish is just a dialect, but I'd like to clarify anyway, that Irish is a language.  It has it's own language ISO code.  I want to translate the Game Center interfaces so that users do not have to read English within an Irish Language app. It is important that minority language users are afforded the right to communicate entirely within their own language and not have English thrust upon them.  Apple et al if they cannot do it themselves should at least allow others to facilitate that.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D (for notification's sake) Just thought I'd chime in to say Gaelic is a grouping of multiple languages (e.g. Irish Gaelic and Scots Gaelic), much like Chinese is a grouping of Cantonese and Mandarin (perhaps et al.). They're mutually unintelligible even if they use the same script. As for the question, *what you see is what you've got*. There are far more languages (some more widely-spoken than Irish Gaelic) not included on that list, but I suppose Apple chose the languages that the modern world would know at least one of. Still, it doesn't take much to generalize the idea…